# Changes to internet explorer DOM object not changing DomElement in powershell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to automate a process with a third party vendor through a web interface using powershell.

The login process is followed by a pop up window. This pop up window does not exist in the html until the login button is clicked. I can see the changes occur after the click by inspecting the html in firefox inspector.

The problem I'm having is the DomElement Object does not reflect the changes that occur to DOM in Internet Explorer. Is there a way to refresh/reload the object?

I can not interact with this popup menu since I can't get a handle on its buttons.

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$facility = "*****"
$username="******"

$password="*******"

$ie.Navigate("https://udsmrweb.udsmr.org/UDSCentral2015/CentralLogin/Index")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$facilityfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txtFacility')
$facilityfield.value = "$facility"
$userfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txtLoginName')
$userfield.value = "$username"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txtPassword')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"

$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('btnCredLogin')
$Link.click()


While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$butt = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") 

foreach ( $button in $butt ) {
    write-host( $button | Format-table | out-string )

}
```

The last foreach grabs all the inputs from the DOM but those returned do not include the 2 inputs in the pop up yet they are in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue in my side. As I don't have the account, so I can just test till [this pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Tou.jpg) show. If using the scripts you provided, I can get all the inputs except the "OK" button in the pop up.

I think that's because the DOM of the pop up hasn't fully loaded but the `foreach` method has been executed. So I add another wait before I want to grab the inputs like below, then I can get the "OK" button in the pop up:

```
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

Start-Sleep 5  # another wait 

$butt = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") 

foreach ( $button in $butt ) {
    write-host( $button | Format-table | out-string )
}
```

I think the situation is the same in your case. You could try to add another wait before grabbing the inputs.